# PHP echo total number of rows from SQL query

Tags: php, sql

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here. I've searched similar issues on here with no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
$check = "SELECT Number FROM advisors";
$result = mysqli_query($check);
$count = mysqi_num_rows($result);

echo $count;
```

Comment: If you only want the number of rows `SELECT count(*) as cnt FROM advisors`

Comment: Also, `mysqli_query` takes a `mysqli` object as its first parameter.

Comment: You have a typo, `mysqi_num_rows` should be `mysqli_num_rows`.

Comment: oh no still mysqli_query around the block

Answer (score 2):

You should use php prepare statement like this

```
$count  = 0;
$mysqli = new mysqli(host, dbUser, dbPassword, dbName);
mysqli_set_charset($mysqli, "utf8");
$sql    = "select count(*)  from advisors";
if ($stmt   = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, $sql))
{
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $c);
    if (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt))
    {
        $count = $c;
    }
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
return $count;
```

For more information, here is the link for php prepare statement
[Documentation of php prepare statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: It's helpful to the asker to include a link to the documentation for the method that you recommend with your answers: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 0):

You should use COUNT in query and see if it works,
"SELECT COUNT (number) as number FROM advisors";
By the way, I noticed a typo in $count, it should be $count = mysqli_num_count($result).